# Is it possible to merge multiple HTML elements into one script in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple element used in HTML, the script is same. So is it possible to merge multiple HTML elements into one script in jQuery? The more shorten code is much easy to manage.

**To Be:**

```
$("#edit_rules_form input select textarea").each(function(){
    if(!$(this).val()){
        $(this).tooltip("show");
        checkfieldvalue = false;
        $(this).on("focus", function(){
            $(this).tooltip("hide");
        });
    }
});
```

**Current jQuery:**

```
$("#edit_rules_form input").each(function(){
    if(!$(this).val()){
        $(this).tooltip("show");
        checkfieldvalue = false;
        $(this).on("focus", function(){
            $(this).tooltip("hide");
        });
    }
});

// Tooltip for <select> dropdown
$("#edit_rules_form select").each(function(){
    if(!$(this).val()){
        $(this).tooltip("show");
        checkfieldvalue = false;
        $(this).on("focus", function(){
            $(this).tooltip("hide");
        });
    }
});

// Tooltip for <textarea> box
$("#edit_rules_form textarea").each(function(){
    if(!$(this).val()){
        $(this).tooltip("show");
        checkfieldvalue = false;
        $(this).on("focus", function(){
            $(this).tooltip("hide");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Your selector is wrong, it needs to be `$("#edit_rules_form input, #edit_rules_form select, #edit_rules_form textarea")`

Comment: you mean simplify your code ? from three `$(el)` to just become one ?; edit :  upvote for @Nick answer

Comment: yes, to simplify the code.

Comment: @Nick, thank you, I will make the correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write multiple selectors using `comma` - https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/.

```
$("#edit_rules_form input, #edit_rules_form select, #edit_rules_form textarea").each(function(){
    if(!$(this).val()){
        $(this).tooltip("show");
        checkfieldvalue = false;
        $(this).on("focus", function(){
            $(this).tooltip("hide");
        });
    }
});
```